# Pre-compactness in $L \log L$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, weak-convergence, orlicz-spaces

As far as I know Zygmund class of Orlicz spaces or "$L \log L$" is defined as an Orlicz space with the Young function  $Q(t) = t \sqrt{\ln(1+t)}$ (or something similar to this in different references).

I wanted to ask does anyone know about the (weak) pre-compactness condition of this space? If for example I have a sequence $\{ \rho_n\}$ s.t. $\Vert \rho_n\Vert_{L_Q} \leq C$ (where $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L_Q}$ denotes the Zygmund norm) can I obtain a (weak) convergent subsequence?

Thank you

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. Just a comment on  terminology: I don't _think_ you should call L log L the "Zygmund space". I've never seen it called that - the term Zygmund space _is_ used for something else: The space of continuous functions $f$ such that $|f(x-h)-2f(x)+f(x+h)|=O(h)$.

Comment: Thank you, this is also the thing that I found a lot in the literature. I borrowed that term from p. 251 here
 https://books.google.de/books?id=74rZtlobEJoC&pg=PA251&dq=Zygmund+orlicz+space&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih7fTXhcPKAhVIEywKHaaMCG4Q6AEIOTAE#v=onepage&q=Zygmund&f=false.
Actually it is mentioned "Logarithmic Zygmund classes" of Orlicz space. Do you suggest the change in my question to get better answers?

Comment: Possible L log L in the title would be better - I only saw your post because I thought it was about what I think of as the Zygmund space. I doubt it will really matter, though.